# Sending json array by Ajax to ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax

I try to send string array by Ajax to method in ASP.NET and it look like this:

JAVASCRIPT

```
function sendArray(someParam) {
    var array = [];

    array[0] = 'first';
    array[1] = 'second';

    var jsonArray = JSON.stringify(array);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'Default.aspx/SendArray',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: '{ "someParam": "someParam", "stringArray": ' + jsonArray + ' }',

        success: function (response) {
            $('#AjaxResult').html('OK');
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $('#AjaxResult').html('<span id="AjaxResultErrorText"><b>There is an error in your request:</b><br />' + errorThrown + '</span>');
        },
        beforeSend: function () {
            $('#AjaxResult').html('<div id="ProgressBar">Loading...</div>');
        },
        complete: function () {
        }
    });
}
```

ASP.NET

```
[WebMethod]
public static void SendArray(string stringArray)
{
    int foo = 1;
}
```

In debuger variable jsonArray  look like this: "["first","second"]"

but I allways have an error called Internal Server Error and I can figure out why.

If I send normal strings or integers everything works fine.

Can somebody explain me why this solution with array doesn't work?

Comment: As the error message says, the error is on the server side. Your AJAX call looks fine, please show us your server side code

Comment: can you please post `SendArray web method`  code

Comment: I edited my question, now there is asp.net method.

Comment: you need to receive array of stirngs = (string[] stringArray)

Comment: Mwell, `"["first","second"]"` is technically a string. If there is an error, it is not an ajax error.

Answer (score 0):

you can send array as a base64 string from ajax

`var jsonArray = btoa(JSON.stringify(array));`

then you can serialize it from codebehind

`stringArray =  Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(stringArray));`